# fitting video in slider (Bootstrap 4.0)

Tags: html, css, video, slider, bootstrap-4

For my school I have to do a website with a video slider. I chose to work with bootstrap 4.0. So far I got a template from it and tried to put a video inside it on one of the sliders. Unfortunately the video won't be shown full. I would like to have it fitting in the slider. (and of course that in the left and in the right of the video will be only the arrows to slide right or left)
Right now it looks like that:
[So in the width its full, but the height you cant see anything](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4QUm.jpg)

what i would like to have is that:
[it fits in the slider with his whole width and height. if you scale the window, the white blocks should get smaller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frnz2.png)

Here is the code I'm using:

```css
/*!
 * Start Bootstrap - Half Slider (https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/half-slider)
 * Copyright 2013-2017 Start Bootstrap
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-half-slider/blob/master/LICENSE)
 */

@charset "UTF-8";

/* Body */

body {
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}

.carousel-item {
  height: 65vh;
  min-height: 300px;
  background: no-repeat center center scroll;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.carousel-item iframe {
  margin-top: 55px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.tales {}

.iframe {
  max-height: 40% !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <title>Half Slider - Start Bootstrap Template</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  <link href="css/half-slider.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

  <!-- Navigation -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Fact Attack</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home
                <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
              </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About us</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <header>
    <!--Carousel Wrapper-->
    <div id="video-carousel-example2" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
      <!--Indicators-->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#video-carousel-example2" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#video-carousel-example2" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#video-carousel-example2" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
      <!--/.Indicators-->
      <!--Slides-->
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <!-- First slide -->
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <!--Mask color-->
          <div class="view">
            <!--Video source-->
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 video-fluid"><iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/193266260" width="1920" height="1080" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe></div>

            <div class="mask rgba-indigo-light"></div>
          </div>

          <!--Caption-->
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <div class="animated fadeInDown">
              <h3 class="h3-responsive text-dark">Light mask</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--Caption-->
        </div>
        <!-- /.First slide -->

        <!-- Second slide -->
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <!--Mask color-->
          <div class="view">
            <!--Video source-->
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 video-fluid"><iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/193266260" width="1920" height="1080" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe></div>

            <div class="mask rgba-indigo-light"></div>
          </div>

          <!--Caption-->
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <div class="animated fadeInDown">
              <h3 class="h3-responsive">Super light mask</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--Caption-->
        </div>
        <!-- /.Second slide -->

        <!-- Third slide -->
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <!--Mask color-->
          <div class="view">
            <!--Video source-->
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 video-fluid"><iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/193266260" width="1920" height="1080" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe></div>

            <div class="mask rgba-indigo-light"></div>
          </div>

          <!--Caption-->
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <div class="animated fadeInDown">
              <h3 class="h3-responsive">Strong mask</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--Caption-->
        </div>
        <!-- /.Third slide -->
      </div>
      <!--/.Slides-->
      <!--Controls-->
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#video-carousel-example2" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#video-carousel-example2" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
      <!--/.Controls-->
    </div>
    <!--Carousel Wrapper-->
  </header>

  <!-- Page Content -->
  <section class="py-5">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Half Slider by Start Bootstrap</h1>
      <p>The background images for the slider are set directly in the HTML using inline CSS. The rest of the styles for this template are contained within the
        <code>half-slider.css</code> file.
      </p>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- Footer -->
  <footer class="py-5 bg-dark">
    <div class="container">
      <p class="m-0 text-center text-white">Copyright &copy; Your Website 2018</p>
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
  </footer>

  <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
  <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Thank you for your help, and just tell me if you need to know something more :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to fix your layout. All the content of the body should be inside a `container`, `row`, and `col-12`.

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

All of the carousel related code should go inside the `col-12`. Doing so, the carousel's width is the same as that of the `nav`, and there are free space on both sides of it.

The controllers are positioned `absolute`. Two of their parents are positioned `relative`. If you do not have enough information on CSS positioning, read this [post](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/).

There are a couple of ways to get the controllers outside of the carousel.

## Method 1

1. Put the two controllers code below the container.

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#video-carousel-example2" role="button" data-slide="prev">
  <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon bg-danger" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="carousel-control-next" href="#video-carousel-example2" role="button" data-slide="next">
  <span class="carousel-control-next-icon bg-danger" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
```

3. Put all the above code inside an another element with `position-relative` class.

```html
<div class="position-relative">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">




      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#video-carousel-example2" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon bg-danger" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#video-carousel-example2" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon bg-danger" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>

</div>
```

Check this [pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aGKVwa)

## Method 2

Override the `position` property of carousel and the `col-12` using the code below. They are relatively positioned.

```css
.position-initial {
  position: initial !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="postion-relative">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <header class="col-12 position-initial">
        <!--Carousel Wrapper-->
        <div id="video-carousel-example2" class="carousel slide carousel-fade position-initial" data-ride="carousel">

        </div>
      </header>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, since the `div` with `position-relative` class has full width and the controllers are `absolutely` positioned, the controller are inside the `full-width` div.

Check this [pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aGKVwa)